# Nexus Repository Manager and blob unknown: blob unknown to registry [Windows Image]

Tags: nexus

I am trying to push a Windows docker Image to a Nexus Repository Manager version 3.3.1 running on Ubuntu Linux.  I am getting blob unknown: blob unknown to registry.  BTW, pushing Linux Docker images works fine.

Can you use Nexus Repository manager running on Linux to store both Linux And Windows Docker images?  If so, how is that done?

P.S. I am pushing from a Windows 10 Computer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see this error :   `docker manifest blob unknown: blob unknown to registry`  when by mistake my script which makes docker commands gets launched more than once at a time ... I just put a lock file wrapper script around it to prevent this from happening ... ubuntu 16.04 while running a private local docker repository ... no Windows here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known request: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-11865

You can read up a bit about it at that link. No ETA for support as of yet.